# What is the appropriate threshold for accuracy in logistic regression?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

Let there is a dataset whose labels are `{0,1}`, and we need to train a neural network model for the logistic regression problem. I need to calculate the accuracy. To do that, I can't compare the label with the predicted value, because they are not the same at all. The predicted value might be 0.9452 while the corresponding label is 1. I would like to know what is the appropriate value as the maximum difference between the label and the predicted value?

Comment: 0.5 is already a good value in most cases. In cases where false positive is better than false negative, you can lower that down.

Comment: It would be subjective. How is your accuracy value of test dataset in different threshold? I think it also depends on structure of neural network. What neural network models did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When labels are 0 or 1, the common threshold that is applied is 0.5

However from a theory standpoint there is no ideal threshold value. For example, if the dataset contains imbalanced classes, a threshold that reflects this imbalance may do better.

So 0.5 is commonly used and empirically good, but there are no guarantees it will be best.